# Allignment of "Chapter"

Tags: positioning

I am trying to format the chapter of a report in the following way
[image]

The `1` should be at the right, with a small `Chapter` writing. But with my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{emptypage}

%\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\linespread{1.3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
  \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
  \fontsize{50}{50}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
  \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filright\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-4pt}
{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}
%\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}}
%\setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
\begin{document}
    \input{abstract.tex}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
 \clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    \include{ch1}
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\end{document}
```

although I have given explicitly `{\filright\bfseries}`, but the 1 is getting placed at the center. How to do the right positioning?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use filright and filleft at the same time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\linespread{1.3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
    \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
    \fontsize{50}{50}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
    \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries}
{\filleft{\Huge Chapter }\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-4pt}
{\titlerule[1.5pt]\Huge}[{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}
%\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}}
%\setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Title chapter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i think the OP also wants a`CH` preceding the numeric `1`